# How to improve the query performance it taking 30 sec to execute the query MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

1. I am using node is along with mongoose.while I am executing this query its taking 30+ sec for execution
2. I think its due to looping how to improve the performance can anyone guide me I am new to mongoose

```js
companies
  .findById(
    {
      _id: companyProfile,
    },
    function(err, company) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: "Some Error Occured!",
        });
      } else {
        var responseJson = [];
        company.ambulances.forEach(function(doc) {
          Gps.find({
            $and: [
              {
                device: doc.deviceId,
              },
              {
                longitude: {
                  $exists: true,
                  $ne: "",
                },
              },
              {
                locationDate: {
                  $exists: true,
                  $ne: "",
                },
              },
              {
                latitude: {
                  $exists: true,
                  $ne: "",
                },
              },
            ],
          })
            .sort({
              $natural: -1,
            })
            .limit(1)
            .exec(function(err, gpsLocations) {
              if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                  message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err),
                });
              } else {
                responseJson.push({
                  gps: gpsLocations,
                });
                if (
                  company.ambulances.length === responseJson.length
                ) {
                  res.json(responseJson);
                }
              }
            });
        });
      }
    },
  )
  .populate("ambulances");
```

Comment: Start with putting all the `doc.deviceId` into an array and then do a query with `{ device: {$in: deviceIds}, ....}`. That may already make it much faster. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0):

Well, first try to convert the callbacks to Promises, in order the code to be easier to understand. Now about the speed, you can match all the `Gps` objects using the `$in` operator. So the result will be something like that.

```
try {
  const company = await companies.findById({ _id: companyProfile });

  const gpsLocations = await Gps.find({
    $and: [
      {
        device: { $in: company.ambulances },
      },
      {
        longitude: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: "",
        },
      },
      {
        locationDate: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: "",
        },
      },
      {
        latitude: {
          $exists: true,
          $ne: "",
        },
      },
    ]
  }).sort({
    $natural: -1,
  }).populate("ambulances");

  return res.json(gpsLocations.map(gpsLocation => ({
    gps: gpsLocation,
  })));
} catch(e) {
  return res.status(400).send({
    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err),
  });
}
```